# Using ADB : How to get file modification date command

Tags: android, shell, adb

I have following command to get file date with time

```
adb shell ls -l /sdcard/sample.txt
Result of this command :
-rwxrwxr-x system   sdcard_rw      676 2013-09-24 11:23 sample.txt
```

Now, I want **2013-09-24 11:23** time with seconds as well.  like **2013-09-24 11:23:11**

How I will get file modification date including seconds.

Thanks.. :)

Answer (score 6):

If you have a stat command:

```
stat -c %y /sdcard/sample.txt
```

Seconds since Epoch

```
stat -c %Y /sdcard/sample.txt
```

Comment: how to execute it. it shows me "stat" is not an internal or external commanad. thanks for reply

Comment: @SachinJ Seems like you don't have stat. Perhaps you could have the tool if you have busybox installed, although it might affect your other commands as well which based themselves from toolbox instead. If you have busybox you can try `busybox stat -c '%y' /sdcard/sample.txt`

Answer (score 0):

By tweaking the code posted, I was able to get it worked using this command :

```
adb -d shell ls -l time-style="+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" path_to_file_in_device
```

The output is :

```
-rw-rw-r-- root     sdcard_rw 22357385 2013-09-25 22:42 launcher.apk
```

Comment: if you look closely, you still don't get the number of seconds in this display; this command is not doing what you thought it does; in fact, it just makes an attempt to interpret the "time-style=..." as a pattern that does not match anything, and proceeds to listing the path_to_file_in_device instead.

Use `stat` command if you have a modern Android OS

Answer (score -2):

ls -l --time-style="+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" /sdcard/sample.txt

Comment: It giving me result like that :--time-style=+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S: No such file or directory
-rwxrwxr-x system   sdcard_rw      676 2013-09-24 11:23 sample.txt

Comment: Make sure to have the time format in quotes. There is a whitespace in the above example format, so that format must be quoted. And make sure, that the file is really available.

Comment: Maybe the ls command of adb has no time-style ability. Give this a try: ls --full-time /sdcard/sample.txt

Comment: Android does not come with your regular shell commands, and bundles toybox or busybox or other similar swiss army knife that is not aware of the --full-time or --time-style switches. This option would work on Linux, but not on Android.